# How to count json items in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have table channels:

```
+----+----------------+---------+
| id | sort           | bouquet |
+----+----------------+---------+
|  1 | ["2","3","73"] | ["1"]   |
| 12 | ["3","73"]     | ["28"]  |
+----+----------------+---------+
```

And need to get count items in sort field for specific boquet...for example:

bouquet  1 have 3 sort items
bouquet 12 have 2 sort items

I try using this query in mysql but i did not get idea how can i calculate number of items in sort field:

```
SELECT COUNT(sort) AS total_channels 
FROM channels 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(bouquet, 'one', "1") IS NOT NULL;
```

I always get:

```
+----------------+
| total_channels |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

Which is incorrect.

Comment: Have you read about [JSON_LENGTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length)?

Comment: Using SELECT JSON_LENGTH(bouquet) FROM channels; i get 1 as result

Comment: Then try `SELECT JSON_LENGTH(sort) FROM channels;`

Comment: Yes i forget to put sort now it returns correct count values but can you please write here how to put WHERE bouquet="1"? bouqet is json type ["1"] so i can'not use bouquet="1"

Comment: There is another function JSON_DEPTH() .... see if that helps.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Using above help i come to this:

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(sort) FROM channels WHERE bouquet='["1"]';
```

And i get correct count:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_LENGTH(sort) FROM channels WHERE bouquet='["28"]';
+-------------------+
| JSON_LENGTH(sort) |
+-------------------+
|                 2 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```